# Implement c++ function pointer with function parameters

Tags: c++, c

Suppose I have a c++ class A with a static member B

```
class A{
  static bool B( int * );
};
```

now suppose I want to create a function pointer for the method B. How it's possible to implement??

I can do it without any parameter like :

```
bool ( *p) (  );
p=& A::B(  ) ;
```

but for my code I have to pass parameter. How to do it?

Comment: Have you looked around at any resources on function pointers?

Comment: @chris Honestly, does he seem so?

Comment: what is the problem with ` bool ( *p) ( ); p=& A::B( ) ;` ? you seem to say it works !? Tell us what is the problem. `bool ( *p) ( ); p=& A::B;` would probably be better.

Comment: @StephaneRolland: That does not work. He is mixing taking the address and the evaluation of the function...

Comment: Why are you worrying about function pointers in C++ ? You should be using polymorphism or any other O.O. mechanism to deal with whatever issue you're having...

Comment: Search the C++ FAQ for "pointer to member function".

Answer (score 4):

You missed the parameter in declaration of p

```
bool ( *p) (int*); // define p, note: p is a function with a 1 int* parameter
p=&A::B; // take the address of the B - no brackets here, since it is not a function call
int ii = 1;
bool b = p(&ii); // call B with a parameter
```